# Gradle 3.0 Splits don't work

Tags: android, gradle

In my gradle script I've configured to split apks by architecture:

```
android {

    [...]

    splits {
        abi {
            enable gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":app:assembleRelease")
            reset()
            include "x86", "arm64-v8a", "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
            universalApk true
        }
    }
}
```

When i run in Android Studio the `Build signed APK` everything works as intended. However as soon as i use `gradlew` the splits are not generated, only the universal apk does get build.

> Used command: `./gradlew clean :app:assembleRelease`

Unfortunately I can't use the Android Studio built-in generation because of CI/CD tools.

I use this code in my `build.gradle` to change version numbers, I don't think this causes the issue:

```
// dífferent version codes for different abis
// https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
ext.abiCodes = ['arm64-v8a': 3, armeabi: 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, x86: 4]
import com.android.build.OutputFile

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def baseAbiVersionCode = project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))
        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {
            output.versionCodeOverride = baseAbiVersionCode + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

Versions:

- `compileSdkVersion 26`
- `buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'`
- `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1`

It worked perfectly with **Gradle 2**, after the update to Gradle 3 it seems broken. How can I get it to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Gradle 3.0 there are some changes according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_api):

> Using the Variant API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the
>   new plugin.It still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK name
>   during build time. The complicated tasks that involve accessing **outputFile**
>   objects no longer work. That's because variant-specific tasks are no
>   longer created during the configuration stage. This results in the
>   plugin not knowing all of its outputs up front, but it also means
>   faster configuration times.

This means our plugin is able to get the outputFile for the AndroidManifest, and therefore can't unable to add a Build UUID for the variant being built.

Google have stated that they will add new APIs to provide similar functionality, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any timeline on that yet.

In your context, the issue is with your **build.gradle** code you can no longer use the **outputFile** object.So, this is why it is broken with Gradle 3.

Also, See this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64747519) reported on the issue tracker.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "x86", "arm64-v8a", "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

May be gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":app:assembleRelease") returns false everytime, so it is not generating multiple apks.